# How to disable Resharper "Find Code Issues" in a Visual Studio solution folder?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

In Resharper, I'm trying to fix all errors find in "Find Code Issues".

In Visual Studio, I have a [Solution Folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haytww03(v=vs.90).aspx) with a bunch of JavaScript librairies and MarkDown files.

When I run "Find Code Issues", it analyses and reports files such as `﻿<Doc>\swagger-ui\lib\handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js`

I tried the [Skip Files and Folders](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/06/26/preventing-items-from-being-analyzed-in-resharper/) feature, but:

- It won't let me add any of the Solution Folders through Add Folder
- It will still run code analysis on items with these different file masks:

  - `\\doc\\`
  - `<Doc>`

I can't seem to find any documentation on achieving this.

So my question is: How can I ignore a Visual Studio Solution Folder in Resharper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recently worked around this issue by creating a dummy project with all the things that were in the solution folder. After that, you can use the skip files and folders feature mentioned.

Comment: That's an unfortunate workaround, but it looks like it's the way to go! Thanks!